# Create empy pandas DataFrame with DateTimeIndex for random time delta values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to create an empty `DataFrame` for which I will then constantly be appending rows to using the time stamp when the data arrives as index.

This is to code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'],index=pd.DatetimeIndex(freq='s'))
df.loc[event.get_datetime()] = event.get_data()
```

The problem Im having is with `freq` in the `DateTimeIndex`, the data is not arriving at any predefined intervalls, it is ju when some event tiggers. And also in the code above I need to specify a start and enddate for the index I dont want that I just want to be able to append rows whenever they arrive.

Comment: Create a dataframe, and blank it by passing df.index to the drop function. Then add the date/time as a string and deal with the conversion later

Comment: Your code does not run. Please fix it.

Comment: How can I fix it, its just an example code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set up empty with `pd.to_datetime`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], index=pd.to_datetime([]))
```

Then do this

```
df.loc[pd.Timestamp('now')] = pd.Series([1, 2], ['a', 'b'])
df

                            a  b
2018-06-10 20:52:52.025426  1  2
```

Comment: Is there a way to name the index for example index=pd.to_datetime([], name='startime')

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of `DateTimeIndex` is `data`. Try setting `data` to an empty list. If you want to define the start time, end time, or frequency, take a look at the other arguments for `DateTimeIndex`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], index=pd.DatetimeIndex([], name='startime'))
```

If you're trying to index on time delta values, also consider

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], index=pd.TimedeltaIndex([]))
```